# AWS CDK: How to get AWS Subnets by tags?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

How can I get subnets based on their tags using AWS CDK?
The VPC I need to use contains multiple isolated subnets and I only want the ones with a particular tag e.g. Name=Foobar.

Comment: You can't do that in CDK. The list of filters for subnet selection can be seen here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.SubnetFilter.html. You can have a custom resource look up your subnet, but it will not be able to return more than one

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I actually now created a script that needs to be run before running `cdk synth`. 
Not 100% happy. See answer to question.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I have not found a perfect solution, but as a workaround I implemented a bash script that needs to be run before any `cdk` commands to get the correct subnet ids.
As I have multiple accounts and therefore profiles, I needed to iterate over them.

```
for profile in $profiles; do
  echo $profile
  echo "$(aws ec2 describe-subnets --filters "Name=tag:Tier,Values=application" --query "Subnets[*].SubnetId" --profile $profile)"
done
```

```
PROFILE_DEV
[
    "subnet-123",
    "subnet-124"
]
PROFILE_QA
[
    "subnet-222",
    "subnet-223"
]
```

I then add the console output to my project config and parse the information to the stack that requires it.

```
/**
 * Run get_application_subnets.sh script to get application subnet ids
 */
const applicationSubnets = {
  DEV: [
    'subnet-123',
    'subnet-124',
  ],
  QA: [
    'subnet-222',
    'subnet-223',
  ],
```

Comment: You could just write that data to a json file (committed to git) and read it from the file in your CDK code. This would work similar to AWS CDK's lookups, which are stored in `cdk.context.json`.

Comment: Valid point, thing is I have my configuration in Typescript and want to avoid having too granular configuration files. I also parse the subnet ids as part of a larger config object and avoid "lookup" logic at the stack level.